# ESXI 6.0 u2 multipathing configuration with group by prio

Tags: vmware-esxi, storage, storage-area-network, multipath

Is it possible to change the path grouping policy of ESXI 6.0 multipathing to group_by_priority? In essence I want to work with the grouping priorities given by a SAN storage. I didnt see any specific kind of path grouping policy in the GUI VMconsole.

Comment: Can you be a LOT more specific please

Comment: The question is clear. I want to know if grouping policy group_by_priority can be configured in ESXI 6.0 (?) and where and how it can be done(?).

Comment: I certainly dont want round-robin to run in multibus mode for example ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer my own question: It is not possible to change any path grouping policy in ESXI 6.0. That said in all my tests ESXI 6.0 was fully group priority aware by default (which is good, as that is what I am looking for). In all three available modes (fixed, MRU, RR) it properly selected the group priorities.

It should be noted that MRU and fixed only use one single path, which is not sufficient for a large SAN deployment. So Round Robin is the only way to go.
Hope this helps someone along the way. :)

Answer (score 1):

More detail about your storage solution and the equipment involved would be helpful, as that dictates how you configure this. You have to go with the manufacturer/vendor's recommendation.

[Here's the VMware documentation.](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.storage.doc%2FGUID-37F97D1C-4E4F-460B-ACF9-04D1347959CC.html)

These are your options for the vSphere client:

[image]

[image]

Comment: so no option here for path grouping policy

Comment: No, it doesn't exist, at all - which I why I wanted you to add more detail as either it made no sense or you've done zero research of your own.

Comment: Yeah, I don't get this.

Comment: assume a storage pool can be accessed by the primary owner controller and by the secondary, as long as both controllers are up, you want the access _only_ going through primary controller and secondary controller is on active standby. Why is that? IO performance! So that is when group_by_prio comes into play as we can create groups of priorities for channeling the traffic in different ways (over primary). However multipath must recognise the priorities accordingly to work.

Comment: E.g. in Centos 7.2 in round robin mode with path grouping policy set to group_by_prio it will round rob the path group of highest priority, if that fails of next priority and so on ...  that is what I am looking for in ESXI 6.0

Comment: [Used "Fixed" in VMware.](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.storage.doc%2FGUID-37F97D1C-4E4F-460B-ACF9-04D1347959CC.html)